# Scala way to set object field value if null in a Seq/List

Tags: scala, list, seq

What is the nicest way to iterate over Scala Seq/List (or other similar collection for that matter) of objects and set the value of a specific object field in case they are null?

For example, a case class:

```
case class AmazingData(age: Int, name: String)

val ad1 = AmazingData(12, "bar")
val ad2 = AmazingData(12, "foo")
val ad3 = AmazingData(12, null)

val alotOfAmazingData: Seq[AmazingData] = Seq(ad1, ad2, ad3)
```

Now I want to iterate over `alotOfAmazingData` and set the name value for the ones that have null.

Comment: What are these fields? Are they part of a mutable/immutable class? Can you elaborate and post a [MCVE]?

Comment: I been in the middle of an edit, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep the complete collection in tact, you can only use a `map` and contain the predicate inside:

```
val allWithNonNull = 
  alotOfAmazingData
    .map(amazing => if (amazing.name == null) amazing.copy(name = "Some Name") else amazing)
```

If you only care about the null names, you can filter out instances that have the name field set and leave only those with `null`, and then `map` over then and set them via `copy`:

```
val nonNullNames = 
  alotOfAmazingData.withFilter(_.name != null)
                   .map(_.copy(name = "Some Name"))
```

Or using `collect`:

```
val nonNullNames = 
  alotOfAmazingData
    .collect { 
       case amazingData if amazingData.name == null =>
     amazingData.copy(name = "Some Name") 
     }
```

Although I would encourage you to not use `null` at all, and use `Option[String]` instead, making your case class look like this:

```
case class AmazingData(age: Int, name: Option[String])
```

And when you want to work with the optional `name` field, you can use `map` and the likes.

Comment: It's a data that I got from 3-rd party. Have no control over it.

Comment: @StasS Ok. For the completeness of the answer I'll leave it there for any future reference.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to iterate over a collection and to get a version with modified elements is the `map` function.  `map` is a higher order function that iterate over a collection and applies a function to each element, returning the result as a new collection.

```
alotOfAmazingData.map(x => if(x.name == null) x.copy(name = default) else x)
```

A function that takes an AmazingData, checks if name is null and then gives a new AmazingData with a default name if it is, otherwise returning the input unchanged.  This is passed to the map function which applies it to each element of your collection.

Avoiding null in the first place is a better approach of course